# Declare protected variable inside PHP class with variable from outside

Tags: php, ini

I am using adLDAP plugin (not really relevant), and there's a standard PHP class. Inside this class there's 2 protected variables (admin user and admin password).

I need to declare these two variables with data from an .ini file, that I load with parse_ini_file. How do I do this? I can't get it to work. Example:

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("somefile");
// username comes like $ini_array["php_value ad.username"]
class someClass {
    protected $adminUSER = "";
    protected $adminPW = "";
}
```

Comment: why do you need to do it from outside? Put the ini parser inside a method or the constructor and set the values there. or provider setters/getters for them.

Comment: As long as it is permanent and I don't have to declare user/password everytime I call the class, I'm happy - inside or outside doesn't matter, as long as it takes it from the .ini file. My knowledge about PHP classes is quite small :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setters this way:

```
class someClass
{
    protected $adminUSER = "";
    protected $adminPW = "";

    public function setAdminUser($adminUser)
    {
        $this->adminUSER = $adminUser ;
    }

    public function setAdminPw($adminPW)
    {
        $this->adminPW= $adminPW;
    }
}

$classInstance = new someClass();
$classInstance->setAdminUser('AdminUser');
$classInstance->setAdminPw('AdminPw');
```

And if you can't modify your class, use heritage:

```
class myClass extends someClass
{
    public function __construct($adminUser, $adminPW)
    {
        $this->adminUSER = $adminUser ;
        $this->adminPW= $adminPW;
    }
}

$myInstance = new myClass('UserAdmin', 'Password);
```

Or both heritage and setters... Or simply inherit and read the configuration in the constructor:

```
class myClass extends someClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $ini_array = parse_ini_file("somefile");
        $this->adminUSER = $ini_array['adminUser'] ;
        $this->adminPW= $ini_array['adminPassword'];
    }
}
```

Then call your new class, it should be auto-initialized:

```
$myInstance = new myClass();
```

Comment: Thank you! I think, I have figured out that method, but I would like it to be permanent, so I don't need to do it every time I call the class. Is that possible?

Comment: You can inherit the class, and read the settings in the constructor. I'll add the example.

Comment: Thanks! Will I then need to call myClass or someClass?

Comment: @ChristianBundgaard Call the new class (sse example). If my answer helps you, please consider accepting and upvote it :)